# possible to using defined name from class outside of class?

Tags: c++

I want to keep the actual struct hidden, but provide a interface name for user.

so my code goes:

```
class A
{
private:
   struct B{...}; 
public:
 using BPtr = B*;
 B* funct(){...};
}
```

my usage would be

```
A a;
BPtr p = a.funct();
```

Comment: This works the way it is, as long as you're not trying to dereference the result of a.funct() EDIT: actually, works even if you dereference it

Comment: Though it would be `A::BPtr p = a.funct()`.

Comment: @lionkor I think yours work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full name is `A::BPtr`, so this will work:

```
A::BPtr p = a.funct();
```

On the other hand, this is pretty pointless, as only the *name* "B" is private – the class definition isn't.

For example,

```
class A
{
private:
   struct B{ int x = 1234; } b; 
public:
 using BPtr = B*;
 B* funct(){ return &b; };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A::BPtr b = a.funct();
    std::cout << b->x << std::endl;
}
```

outputs "1234", and so does

```
class A
{
private:
   struct B{ int x = 1234; } b; 
public:
 B funct(){ return b; };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.funct().x << std::endl;
}
```

even though `A::B b = a.funct();` would not compile (but `auto b = a.funct()` would).

Lesson: if you hand someone a thing, they can use it - even if they don't know what to call it.

Answer (score 3):

An addition to the answer by @molbdnilo:

Note that even if you don't expose the struct pointer as `BPtr`, it's not private anymore once you're returning it outside the class.

Here is an example of using the struct outside of the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A 
{
private:
    struct B { int num; };
public:
    B* funct() { return new B {}; }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    typedef std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*a.funct())> B;

    B b { 3 };
    std::cout << b.num << std::endl;
}
```